# override symfony2 bundle controller actions

Tags: symfony

/src/Vendor/JobQueueBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

```
namespace Vendor\JobQueueBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use JMS\JobQueueBundle\Controller\JobController;

/**
* @Route("/jobs")
*/
class DefaultController extends JobController
{
    /**
    * @Route("/index")
    */
    public function indexAction()
    {
        die();
    }
}
```

/app/config/routing.yml

```
vendor_api_job_queue:
    resource: "@VendorJobQueueBundle/Controller/"
    type:     annotation
    prefix:   /

JMSJobQueueBundle:
    resource: "@JMSJobQueueBundle/Controller/"
    type: annotation
```

/src/Syntetik/API/JobQueueBundle/SyntetikAPIJobQueueBundle.php

```
namespace Vendor\JobQueueBundle;

use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Bundle\Bundle;

class VendorJobQueueBundle extends Bundle
{
    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'JMSJobQueueBundle';
    }
}
```

When I try to call /jobs/index I get:

```
Method "JMS\JobQueueBundle\Controller\JobController::indexAction" does not exist.
```

DefaultController is completely ignored and not sure why?

Thanks!

Comment: run app/console router:debug | grep  /jobs/index

Comment: `vendor_jobqueue_default_index       ANY    ANY    ANY  /jobs/index`

So it points to the child but it loads the parent...weird...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out the problem with this. It seems it's not symfony2 specific.
The problem is JMS\DiExtraBundle\JMSDiExtraBundle which mess the things around. Just removing that bundle makes everything works by the book.

Thanks!

Comment: Using the JMSDiExtraBundle bundle broke custom table naming. Seems like some caching issue.

Answer (score 3):

It's known and opened issue of JMSDiExtraBundle https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/issues/39 so problem is that DiExtarBundle doesn't lookup parent class for annotations if child class has not at least one JMS annotation, so proxy class isn't generate at the metadata cache (look app/cache/dev/jms_diextra/metadata/)

The quickest solution is leave at least on annotation:

Parent Controller >>

```
<?php

namespace Namespace\SiteBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;

use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;

class IndexController extends Controller 
{   
    /**
     * @DI\Inject("doctrine.orm.entity_manager")
     * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em
     */
    protected $em;

    /**
     * @DI\Inject("namespace.search.manager")
     * @var Namespace\SearchBundle\Services\SearchManager $searchManager
     */
    protected $searchManager;

    /**
     * @DI\Inject("namespace.product.manager")
     * @var Namespace\ProductBundle\Services\ProductManager $productManager
     */
    protected $productManager;

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction() { 
        echo "parent!";
        $defaultCategory = $this->searchManager->getDefaultCategory();
        ....
        return $result;
    }
}
```

Child controller >>

```
<?php

namespace OtherSpace\SiteBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Template;
use JMS\DiExtraBundle\Annotation as DI;

use Namespace\SiteBundle\Controller\IndexController as BaseIndexController;


class IndexController extends BaseIndexController
{
/**
 * The temprary solution base on known JMS/DiExtraBundle open issue https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/issues/39
 * **We need to leave at leat one Inject in child class to get a proxy generated**  
 * 
 * @DI\Inject("doctrine.orm.entity_manager")
 * @var \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager $em
 */
protected $em;

    /**
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     * @Template()
     */
    public function indexAction() { 
        echo "child!";
        $result = parent::indexAction();

        return $result;
    }

}
```

So this way proxy class will be generated for SpaceOther-IndexController and annotations will work

---

I also worked around fix this issue, you can look to my pull request  https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSDiExtraBundle/pull/153